# How do I send a SOAP request to a webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

Are there any tools available to send XML request to a webservice to see if it is functioning?

I tried it pro grammatically by consuming a WSDL in Visual Studio and using the exposed interface but I want to try another way.

Could a tool like soapUI do this?

Thanks

Here is the Request I want to send.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:envelope">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <AccountObject timeFormat="blah"  transactionType ="READ" >
            <AccountObjectDetails>
                <AccountObjectDetailsHeader
                    AccountID="99999999"/>
            </AccountObjectDetails>
        </AccountObject>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: If you know about soapUI, then why don't you try it? This is _exactly_ what soapUI is known for.

Comment: Why not just write your on HTTPRequest? You can pass this as the parameter and see what the response is.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a tool like Fiddler to send your request: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Go into the request builder tab and fill out the details.